# OSM .pbf Files to Raster Mbtiles Format

Tags: openstreetmap, mbtiles, maperitive

I downloaded the osm.pbf files from planetosm and I am using them in an application which will work offline, I need to convert the osm.pbf file to raster mbtiles file, I want to do this for a specific part of the world. I have searched it online and the only solution I could find was using "Maperitive", the application works and does as intended by using its "generate-mbtiles" command but I am performing this action while covering parts of a country and with zoom levels up to 16 which is what I need and the application starts but it is slow with rendering speeds of about 2.5-3 tiles per sec. And after a while it just stops responding, after checking memory usage I see that the app isn't doing anything.

I want to know if there is any other to convert osm.pbf files to raster mbtiles format. I have the time and resource to convert but it should work. Maperitive is not working all the way which is why I am here requesting for help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849406/is-there-a-way-to-generate-a-mbtiles-file-from-osm-pbf-file for alternatives.

Comment: Had already looked at this but these are for mbtiles in vector format. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are three parts to your question:

1. Converting the OSM data into something that you can easily generate raster tiles from.
2. Generating the raster tiles that you want (with whatever map style you want).
3. Converting those tiles into your chosen format.

For (1), one of the options at [the switch2osm site](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) will probably work.

For (2) I'd probably use [render_list_geo.pl](https://github.com/alx77/render_list_geo.pl).  Depending on available resources (you can decide how many threads to run at once) it will take some seconds per tile.  You will need to be patient, but you can monitor progress.

For (3) I'm not sure, but I bet there are other answers at gis.stackexchange.com that cover that part already!